# How to pass backing bean value to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, xhtml, managed-bean

I would like to read the backing bean value in JSF and then pass over to JavaScript, may I know how this can be done?

Backing bean sample code:

```
@ManagedBean(name="enquiry")
@SessionScoped
public class Enquiry {

  public boolean noQuery;

  /** getter and setter **/
}
```

In XHTML sample code, I would like pass the backing bean value and then pass into `showNoQueryPrompt()` like this:

```
<h:commandLink onClick="showNoQueryPrompt(#{enquiry.noQuery})">
</h:commandLink>
```

And then in JavaScript code, I can read the boolean value to determine whether I should prompt or not prompt. Here is the code:

```
<script ...>
   var showNoQueryPrompt(Boolean showPrompt) {

     if( showPrompt == "true" ) {
        alert('No query');
     }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: just drop it into hidden input

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the point, you need to understand that JSF merely produces HTML code and that JS is part of HTML. So all you need to do is to write JSF/EL code accordingly that it *produces* valid HTML/JS code. Indeed, using EL to inline bean properties in the generated JavaScript code like as in your attempt is one of the right ways.

Assuming that this is indeed the *real* code, you however made some syntax mistakes. The `onClick` attribute is invalid. It must be in all lowercase. Otherwise JSF simply won't render the attribute at all.

```html
<h:commandLink value="link" onclick="showNoQueryPrompt(#{enquiry.noQuery})" />
```

JavaScript has no notion of strong typing. The `Boolean` type in function argument is invalid. Remove it. Otherwise you will face a nice JS syntax error (in browser's JS console).

```javascript
function showNoQueryPrompt(showPrompt) {
   if (showPrompt) {
      alert('No query');
   }
}
```

Note that I expect that you understand that this runs *before* commandlink's own `action` is been invoked (you should now have understood; JSF generates HTML; rightclick page in browser and *View Source* to see it yourself). But you didn't cover that in your concrete question (even more, you didn't describe the concrete problem with the given code in the question at all), so I can't give an detailed answer on that.

Comment: That is too bad, I need `enquiry.noQuery` to update 1st before prompting the alert.

Comment: As answered, you have never made the concrete functional requirements clear in the question, so I wasn't able to answer that in detail. But whatever you want is definitely possible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will raise another question as I don't want to pollute the question with extended answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the approach from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-pass-new-hidden-value-to-backing-bean-in-jsf/)

and save your bean field in:

```
<h:inputHidden id="hidden2" value="#{enquiry.noQuery}" />
```

then, call your method using the value of this field.