# dataModel URL javascript function does not populate grid

Tags: javascript, java, json, function

Why won't the grid populate?

I have JSON string generated dynamically using java. (main . java)
[gif image of json string generation][1]

```
  package com.queryData.main;

  import com.queryData.dao.DataDAO;
  import com.queryData.services.JsonServices;
  import java.sql.ResultSet;
  import java.util.List;
  import org.json.JSONObject;

  public class Main {
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    DataDAO datadao = new DataDAO();

    public List<JSONObject> getJsonObject() {
        resultSet = datadao.getResultSet();
        List<JSONObject> resList = JsonServices.getFormattedResult(resultSet);
        return resList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        List<JSONObject> jObj = m.getJsonObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < jObj.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(jObj.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

I have paramQuery grid loading but have a problem with the dataModel to load the data. (index . xhtml)
[gif image of grid loading with no data][2]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
    <!--jQuery dependencies-->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!--ParamQuery Grid files-->
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/pqgrid.min.css" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/pqgrid.min.js" />
        <!--Include Touch Punch file to provide support for touch devices-->    
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js" />   
<script>
$(function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.width = 700;
    obj.height = 400;    
    obj.colModel = [
        { title: "Person ID", width:100, dataIndx: "person_id"},
        { title: "Full Name", width:200, dataIndx: "fullname"},
        { title: "First Name", width:150, dataIndx: "firstname"},
        { title: "Last Name", width:150, dataIndx: "lastname"}
        ];    
    <!-- reference to load remote data -->    
    var dataModel = {
            recIndx: "personid",
            location: "remote",
            sorting: "local",
            paging: "local",
            dataType: "JSON",
            method: "GET",
            sortIndx: "lastname",
            sortDir: "up",            
            url: "main.java"
            , getData: function (dataJSON) {
                var data = dataJSON.data;
                return { data: dataJSON.data };
            }
        }    
    <!-- KEY PART TO LOAD DATA -->       
    $("div#grid_array").pqGrid( obj );
}); 
</script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="grid_array"></div>    
</h:body>
</html>
```

I have altered the URL but do not know how the URL reference should be written, below is the script I am currently trying to correct

```
    <h:head>
    <!--jQuery dependencies-->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!--ParamQuery Grid files-->
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/pqgrid.min.css" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/pqgrid.min.js" />
        <!--Include Touch Punch file to provide support for touch devices-->    
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js" />

<script>
$(function()
{
<!-- reference to load remote data --> 
    var dataModel =
        {
            location: "remote",   
            sorting: "local",                     
            dataType: "JSON",
            method: "GET",
            url: "json",
            getData: function (dataJSON) {return { data: dataJSON.data };}    
        }   
<!-- reference to create column titles -->
    var obj = {dataModel:dataModel};    
    obj.colModel = 
        [
        { title: "Person ID", width:100, dataIndx: "person_id"},
        { title: "Full Name", width:200, dataIndx: "fullname"},
        { title: "First Name", width:150, dataIndx: "firstname"},
        { title: "Last Name", width:150, dataIndx: "lastname"}
        ];
<!-- reference to initiate the request -->      
    $("div#grid_array").pqGrid( obj );
}
); 
</script>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="grid_array"></div>    
</h:body>
```

These are the two servlets that generate the JSON string, I need to modify from being a LIST to a string to generate JSON data in this format.

{"data": [ row1, row2, ..] }

and retrievable through a URL via GET HTTP request in my VIEW index . xhtml

The two beans and the one index VIEW:

first bean -

```
    package com.queryData.services;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonServices {
    public static List<JSONObject> getFormattedResult(ResultSet rs) {
        // List<JSONObject> resList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();      
        List<JSONObject> resList = "{\"data\":" + new ArrayList<JSONObject>() + "}";
        // above is the attempt to modify   

        try {
            // get column names
            ResultSetMetaData rsMeta = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCnt = rsMeta.getColumnCount();
            List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            // loop to get all column names
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCnt; i++) {
                // adding all retrieved column names to List object
                columnNames.add(rsMeta.getColumnName(i).toUpperCase());
            }
            while (rs.next()) {
                // convert each object to an human readable JSON object
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCnt; i++) {
                    String key = columnNames.get(i - 1);
                    String value = rs.getString(i);
                    obj.put(key, value);
                }
                resList.add(obj);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return resList;
    }
}
```

second bean -

```
    package com.queryData.main;

import com.queryData.dao.DataDAO;
import com.queryData.services.JsonServices;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    DataDAO datadao = new DataDAO();

    public List<JSONObject> getJsonObject() {
        resultSet = datadao.getResultSet();
        List<JSONObject> resList = JsonServices.getFormattedResult(resultSet);
        return resList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        List<JSONObject> jObj = m.getJsonObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < jObj.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(jObj.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

VIEW index . xhtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/pqgrid.min.css"/>
    <h:outputScript name="js/pqgrid.min.js"/>           
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"/>
<script>
$(function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.width = 700;
    obj.height = 400;    
    obj.colModel = [
        { title: "Person ID", width:100, dataIndx: "person_id"},
        { title: "Full Name", width:200, dataIndx: "fullname"},
        { title: "First Name", width:150, dataIndx: "firstname"},
        { title: "Last Name", width:150, dataIndx: "lastname"}
        ];
    var dataModel = {
            recIndx: "personid",
            location: "remote",
            sorting: "local",
            paging: "local",
            dataType: "JSON",
            method: "GET",
            sortIndx: "lastname",
            sortDir: "up",            
            url: "main"
            , getData: function (dataJSON) {
                var data = dataJSON.data;
                return { data: dataJSON.data };
            }
        }
    $("div#grid_array").pqGrid( obj );
}); 
</script>   
</h:head>
<h:body>
<div id="grid_array"></div>  
</h:body>
</html>
```

The deployed test app can be viewed at [deployed test run](http://35.166.148.217/faces/index.xhtml)

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if calling the the main.java would return a result to your javascript. I would suggest if you try to call the URL first using Postman or any tool that check if it is indeed really returning a response.

Comment: I cannot find any example of the URL to the JSON string resultset as created in the bean.  Shall try Postman.

Comment: It seems that I get what you want now. You want to retrieve a data from a backing bean and show it via javascript. If that is the case, then you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049745/how-to-pass-backing-bean-value-to-javascript

Comment: carloliwanag, I check the reference you shared -- How to pass backing bean value to JavaScript? -- the solution does not address the actual TOPIC of that post, it reviews the onclick errors of the button, and it also reviews -- How to pass new hidden value to backing bean in JSF -- I do not see anything there that may shed some light on how to retrieve the JSON string being generated by the backing bean.

Comment: In using Postman, what URL would I use to call to test -- returning a response, as I have in the first gif in this post showing a response JSON string being generated by the backing bean.  I just do not know how to reference it in the javascript JQuery GetJson.

Comment: Jon, I just thought you may use the approach of sending the json string into a hidden value from the backing bean and then get the json string from that hidden value using javascript. let me try answering you in a post.

Comment: ok, the json string variable is System.out.println(jObj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follow:

Create a backing bean

Persons.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="persons")
@SessionScoped
public class Persons {
  ResultSet resultSet = null;
  DataDAO datadao = new DataDAO();
  public List<JSONObject> people = JsonServices.getFormattedResult(datadao.getResultSet());
  /** getter and setter **/
}
```

In your xhtml, you add a hidden element where you put data from backing bean

```
<h:inputHidden id="hiddenPeople" value="#{persons.people}" />
```

In your xhtml, javascript section

```
<script>
  $(function() {
     var peopleList = $('#hiddenPeople');
     var peopleJson = JSON.parse(peopleList)
     // display peopleJson
  });
</script>
```

Now, I am not sure if the List people will be converted to a string, so you may want to convert that to a String rather than a List.

Comment: I explored your solution.  I discovered I need to map the servlet and reference it.  I have mapped it in the web . xml file, but I think you are correct I need to convert result set to a string.  Please, can you help with suggestions to modifiy the code.

Comment: thank you.  the solution you presented, I believe came up because I did not address the problem correctly.  The challenge has been partially resolved with YOUR suggestion about the conversion to string
Please view [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415865/convert-java-arraylist-to-array-using-for-loop[link]

Comment: can you please view the other topic, everyone there seems to think I am creating a desktop application, as I reduced the challenge down to its smallest part and by google searching was able to finally get a proper JSON string -- now, my problem is to use that FIFTH of five beans to generate a result that I may reference as a URL in my xhtml VIEW.  I may have to re-write my bean that retrieves and converts the remote MySQL into JSON string -- but I have successfully done that, but now, I am stuck without any ability to reference the JSON string as a URL.

Comment: have you tried putting the value in the <input type='hidden'>?

Comment: how will putting the <input type='hidden'> create the JSON string value to be able to be used in the web.xml as a URL ?

Comment: I think you don't need web.xml here. you just need to reference from your xhtml the managed bean where will you pull the string. have you created the managed bean? if so, in your xhtml, just add <h:inputHidden id="hiddenPeople" value="#{<name of your bean>.<string property where you put the json string>}" />

Comment: can a <input type='hidden'> in the VIEW (xhtml) retrievable through a (referenced in web.xml) URL via GET HTTP request to return the JSON string value ?

Comment: 'System.out.println(responseStr);'
producing 
MySQL Driver Loaded Successfully
Database Connection Successful
{"data":[{"LASTNAME":"Leonard","PERSON_ID":"0","FIRSTNAME":"Erick","FULLNAME":"Erick Leonard"}]}

Comment: I need to retrieve the JSON sting retrievable through a URL via GET HTTP request
for example
[link]http://paramquery.com/pro/products/get
[link]

Comment: then I can suggest that you use jax-rs to expose a 'GET' restful web-service. you can view the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html. I recommend to create a business or service layer which has a reference to your DAO and use that in you web service.