# convert java arraylist to array using for loop

Tags: java, json, org.json

I have viewed the many similar topics here, none have allowed me to resolve:

```
 //how to Convert this arraylist to array string using loop

public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
Main m = new Main();
List<JSONObject> jObj = m.getJsonObject();
for (int i = 0; i < jObj.size(); i++) 
    {
    System.out.println(jObj.get(i));
    }
 }
```

The many examples I have seen all create an array list by adding in the code, I already have the arrayList.  I just need to modify it as an array string and not an arrayList so that I may properly format it as a JSON string with

```
String responseStr = "{\"data\":" +
```

Here is the entire bean :

```
package com.queryData.main;

import com.queryData.dao.DataDAO;
import com.queryData.services.JsonServices;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    DataDAO datadao = new DataDAO();

    public List<JSONObject> getJsonObject()
    {
        resultSet = datadao.getResultSet();
        List<JSONObject> resList = JsonServices.getFormattedResult(resultSet);      
        return resList;
    }
    //how to Convert this arraylist to array string using loop

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
    Main m = new Main();
    List<JSONObject> jObj = m.getJsonObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < jObj.size(); i++) 
        {
        System.out.println(jObj.get(i));
        }
     }
}
```

I tried the following code, but it does not work.

```
package com.queryData.main;

import com.queryData.dao.DataDAO;
import com.queryData.services.JsonServices;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    DataDAO datadao = new DataDAO();

    public List<JSONObject> getJsonObject()
    {
        resultSet = datadao.getResultSet();
        List<JSONObject> resList = JsonServices.getFormattedResult(resultSet);      
        return resList;
    }
    //how to Convert this arraylist to array string using loop

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
    Main m = new Main();
    List<JSONObject> jObj = m.getJsonObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < jObj.size(); i++) 
        {
        //System.out.println(jObj.get(i));
        }

    String[] stringArr = jObj.toArray( new String[] {} );
    for ( String element : stringArr ) {
        System.out.println( element );


     }
    }   
}
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `I just need to modify it as an array string and not an arrayList so that I may properly format it as a JSON string` ... _Huh_ ?

Comment: Show a minimal example of the input json and expected output json to better explain your scenario, please. (and that's presuming you want to output json again, if I'm wrong explain what output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use StringBuilder to build String :

```
List<Object> jObj = m.getJsonObject();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i =0 ; i < jObj.size(); i++){
   sb.append(jObj.get(i).toString());
}
```

Finally `sb.toString()` will be your desired String.

Comment: thank you.  The code you shared returns an error:

Multiple markers at this line
 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<JSONObject> to List<Object>
 - Duplicate local variable jObj

Comment: THANK YOU.  I modified <Object> to <JSONObject> and it worked!  Please how would I be able to ADD the following to create my needed JSON string:
`
String responseStr = "{\"data\":" +
`

Comment: The two additional lines would be something along the below, to add the prefix to the JSON:
`
        String responseStr = "{\"data\":" + serializedProducts + "}";        
        return responseStr;
`

Comment: thank you... one last step, how to return the response variable to use servlet as URL

`
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 { 
 Main m = new Main();
 List<JSONObject> jObj = m.getJsonObject();
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for(int i =0 ; i < jObj.size(); i++)
  {
    sb.append(jObj.get(i).toString());
  } 
   {         
   String responseStr = "{\"data\":[" + sb + "]}";
   System.out.println(responseStr);
   } 
 return responseStr;            
 }
`

Comment: can you please re compose your problem. ? In one paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

you can make some changes : List supports trick like

```
List<Object> jObj = m.getJsonObject();
for(int i =0 ; i < jObj.size(); i++){
   jObj.add(jObj.get(i).toString(), i); // change toString() to whatever u need
}
```

Comment: thank you, would you know how I can return a value without the error?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if we can do that using for loop.
But if you want one without for loop.
We can do:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList5=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arrayList5.add(1000000);
    arrayList5.add(2000000);
    
    //the final array created with the help of toArray
//is of Object type hence create an array first and then pass it as argument
        Integer[] array5=new Integer[arrayList5.size()];
        arrayList5.toArray(array5);
        
//print the array
        for(Integer i: array5) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```