# How to use a JSF component in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have the following javascript in a JSF page. Its basically using `<h:outputText>` statement in javascript if condition::

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    function popup() {
       if (<h:outputText value="#{searchListbean.displayPrintPopup}" />)
                displayPopup('popup');
    }

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

but I have the following error at the console::

**SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'**

The `<` in `<h:outputText>` statement is causing the syntaxError problem.

I thought surrounding the javascript code with `/* <![CDATA[ */` and `/* ]]> */` will  solve it but it didn't.

How do I fix it?

Comment: replace `<h:outputText...` with `<hr/>` and you have the same error. Not jsf related, not java related

Comment: @Kukeltje  what do you mean by replacing it with <hr/>. How do i get my bean statement "searchListbean.displayPrintPopup" executed in the condition?

Comment: JavaScript is a language. ```if (<h:outputText value="#{searchListbean.displayPrintPopup}" />)``` is not JavaScript. How does that HTML tag get there and why?

Comment: That is a different thing... What I proposed was a 'narrow down your problem'... Indicating that the error you get is not jsf related. And adding such a tag in a javascript if statement is very weird anyway. That part looks like an http://xyproblem.info

Comment: Try to simply use `#{searchListbean.displayPrintPopup}` (EL expression) instead of `<h:outputText value="#{searchListbean.displayPrintPopup}" />`

Comment: CDATA only works around data, not around code. It doesn’t change the way that JavaScript is read.

Comment: @JasperdeVries: good catch... I was totally on the wrong foot...

Comment: @JasperdeVries You can use your comment as answer so that i can accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSF component will not be rendered within a `<script>` tag. You could use deferred EL (`#{...}`) though. Make sure that the property or method you are calling is properly escaping the output to be used JavaScript (in your case simply `"true"` or `"false"`).

So, in your case, just use:

```
<script>
  function popup() {
    if (#{searchListbean.displayPrintPopup}) {
      displayPopup('popup');
    }
  }
</script>
```

See also:

- [How to pass backing bean value to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049745/how-to-pass-backing-bean-value-to-javascript)